# Why is this function continuous on $ x \in \mathbb{R} $ where $ x < 1 $?

Tags: complex-analysis

The function is

$$ \exp(\frac{1}{3}\text{log}[(z-1)(z-2)(z-3)]) $$

where

$$ \log[(z-1)(z-2)(z-3)] = \int_4^z{\frac{[(z-1)(z-2)(z-3)]'}{[(z-1)(z-2)(z-3)]}dz} + \log 6 $$

This function is clearly continuous on $ \mathbb{C} \backslash \{ x \in \mathbb{R} : x < 3 \} $ since this is a simply connected domain and $ [(z-1)(z-2)(z-3)]' $ and $ [(z-1)(z-2)(z-3)] $ don't equal zero anywhere in the domain. I don't see how to to show this is continuous on the real axis for $ x \lt 1 $ though. Any thoughts?

Comment: I don't understand your question. Those $x < 1$ are not even part of the domain of your function (the path integral does not give a unique solution)...

Comment: According to my textbook, this function is continuous on x < 1. I can't seem to find a way to prove or disprove this.

Comment: A [related problem](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/388984/show-that-sqrt3z-1z-2z-3-can-be-defined-on-the-entire-plane-minus/389001#389001).

Comment: For $Re(z)=x<1$ the function is single-valued and continuous.

Comment: I asked that related problem, and I still don't understand any of the answers on the continuity of the function. Perhaps you could elaborate your answer a bit more.

Comment: You need to make a correction $ \mathbb{C} \backslash \{ x \in \mathbb{R} : x < 3 \} $. It should be $x<1$.

Comment: Was also asked and answered [here](http://math.stackexchange.com/q/391066/75064), with two different answers.